# Join tables results to individual columns

Tags: php, mysql

**Student table:**

```
(student_id(PK),student_name,subject_enrolled(FK))
```

**Teacher table:**

```
(teacher_id(PK),teacher_name,subject_teaches(FK))
```

**Subject table:**

```
(subject_id(PK),subject_name)
```

How can I put a proper JOIN TABLES query for this such that it will accomodate 5 teachers for different column such that:

> (student_name, teacher_name1, teacher_name2, teacher_name3, teacher_name4, teacher_name5)
>
> (resulted from same subject_enrolled and subject_teaches)

Comment: Can you update example also?.....Your question is not clear to us.

Answer (score 0):

As you added php tag iam splitting the teacher name column using php. Check my code

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(servername, dbusername, dbpassword,database);
 $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT students.student_name,GROUP_CONCAT(teachers.teacher_name) FROM students JOIN teachers WHERE teachers.subject_teaches = students.subject_enrolled GROUP BY students.student_id");
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$student[]=$row["student_name"];
$teacher[]=$row["GROUP_CONCAT(teachers.teacher_name)"];
    }
  echo'<table><tr><th>Student name</th><th>Teacher name1</th><th>Teacher name2</th><th>Teacher name3</th><th>Teacher name4</th><th>Teacher name5</th>       </tr>';
    $sidebar2 = new MultipleIterator();
        $sidebar2->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($student));
        $sidebar2->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($teacher));
          foreach ( $sidebar2 as $value) {
            list($studentname,$teachername) = $value;
         $tarray=explode(",",$teachername);
       echo"<tr><td>$studentname</td>";
      foreach($tarray as $teachern){
      echo"<td>$teachern</td>";
   }
     echo'</tr>';
        }
        echo'</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on you actual tables this is possible in a single SQL statement:-

```
SELECT s.student_name,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t.teacher_name ORDER BY teacher_id), ',', 1) AS teacher_name1,
        IF(COUNT(t.teacher_id) >= 2, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t.teacher_name ORDER BY teacher_id), ',', 2), ',', -1), NULL) AS teacher_name2,
        IF(COUNT(t.teacher_id) >= 3, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t.teacher_name ORDER BY teacher_id), ',', 3), ',', -1), NULL) AS teacher_name3,
        IF(COUNT(t.teacher_id) >= 4, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t.teacher_name ORDER BY teacher_id), ',', 4), ',', -1), NULL) AS teacher_name4,
        IF(COUNT(t.teacher_id) >= 5, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t.teacher_name ORDER BY teacher_id), ',', 5), ',', -1), NULL) AS teacher_name5
FROM student s
LEFT OUTER JOIN teacher t ON s.subject_enrolled = t.subject_teaches
GROUP BY s.student_id
```

However my concern is your table descriptions. Your student table has a student_id as a primary key and then a field for the subject_enrolled. This suggests you have either multiple student_ids for each student, or that subject_enrolled is a delimited field of all the subjects that they are enrolled on.

My SQL above is assuming that student id is not the primary key, hence you can have multiple rows per student / student id.